# Chronicle rulesets/filters

Tags: zebra-savanna

Well I personally think this is very important for chronicle. Being able to add rulesets/filters about what kind of data to store and what not.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. It could be part of a service offering and the users of the API could define their own policies concerning permanent data storage, depending on their regulatory needs, for instance.